# Jquery change text button show more / show less

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I am using jQuery to hide or show elements with a button. 
The button value should change to: `Show more` when elements are hidden and `show less` when elements are shown.

My html code

```
<section>
    <div class="contact_channel" name="<?php echo $this->id; ?>"></div>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <input type="button" class="showMore tiny button" value="Show more">
    </div>

    <div class="show_more" style="display:none;"></div>
</section>
```

My jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showMore').on('click', function () {
            var section = $(this).closest('section'),
                text    = section.find('.show_more'), // use classes, not ID
                state   = text.is(':hidden');
                button  = $(this).find('input');

            text[state?'slideDown':'slideUp'](500);
            button.prop('value', function() {
                return state ? "Show more" : "Show less";
            });
            $('input').show(200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, this part of code doesn't work :

```
        button.prop('value', function() {
            return state ? "Show msdsdfs" : "Show lsdfsdfs";
        });
        $('input').show(200);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: If I understand, you have content inside div with "show_more" class, when you click on the button it display the content (and it change the button value) ?

Comment: yes it display the content but it don't change the button value, that my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the find, since the button has the showMore class

Change this code

```
 button  = $(this).find('input');
```

to

```
 button  = $(this);
```

Comment: It's work fine, can you explain why it didn't work ?

Comment: .find was trying to find a child of the .showMore element - you wanted this to act on the .showMore element, not one of its children